# DOSBox - This program cannot be run in dos mode (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, nasm

Since few weeks, I have been studying Assembly Language Programming, today I installed all the necessary applications to compile an assembly program.

I install DOSBox 0.74, NASM (Assembler), and AFD (Debugger). I mount the drive and see my .asm files correctly. But when I execute the following command:

> nasm firstprogram.asm -o firstprogram.com

it gives me the following error: `This program cannot be run in dos mode`

But when I compile the file through command prompt (cmd) it compiles corrrectly and then I have to go to DOSBox to run AFD and debug the .com file.

Any idea why am I getting this error on DOSBox?

Comment: Where are you executing the first command?

Comment: BTW, what does this has to do with C++?

Comment: @KemyLand Nothing, I'd say. I took the liberty of removing the tag. If the OP feels it's warranted, they can add it back along with a suitable explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're receiving this error message because you're attempting to run the *Windows version of the `nasm` binary* on a virtual *MS-DOS* platform. This isn't supported. Instead, you should download and use the [MS-DOS `nasm` binary](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.09rc1/dos/).

**Explanation**: When you see the details of the [Portable Executable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Layout) (the internal format of .exe, .dll, and some .com files), you'll come across the *MS-DOS stub header*. This header's primary function is to display the message "**This program cannot be run in DOS mode**" when executed on 16-bit [real mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode) operating systems like MS-DOS. This message serves as a warning to the user that the program they're trying to run is incompatible with their current system.

Comment: Or run NASM *outside* DOSBox, only running a debugger and the actual `.com` executable you create inside DOSBox.  You can build as well as edit outside DOSBox with native tools, if that's more convenient.  (e.g. if your editor has a keybind for building and seeking to lines that triggered errors.)  `nasm -f bin` is the default for any version of NASM, so you still don't need any extra options to build a DO binary with it.

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the version that runs in Windows. When you open a directory of a specific version, there are subdirectories for various OS.

For example, here:
https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.12/

If you download the one from /dos folder you will be able to run it in DOSBox, however if you download the one in /win32 folder, you will only be able to run it from Windows.

Answer (score -7):

Probably you are doing so called `console application`. It runs on console, but requires `Windows 95` or never under the hood, mainly for `fat32` support.